# Newly created dashboard in sonarqube for local branch does not show new bugs/issues in the first run

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonar.branch inside a Jenkins job. Also failing it based on quality gate. The new dashboard(of local branch) does not show new Bugs and New issues in first run. I want the newly created project to compare with master branch and show the new issues in first run itself. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Is Jenkins shows issues generated inside build logs, and hence do you able to get issues count during running build on current branch ?